# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to return a true/false value to a page with an ajax request, but I am getting an error of:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'
> Here is my code:

```cs
public ActionResult CheckSignedIn()
{
    return _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User);
}
```

I am rather new to programming, and thus I'm not sure what to change `ActionResult` out for, nor what `ActionResult` even means. Any solution or explanation would be appreciated

Comment: would return Json(_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)); work?

Comment: Try with `return OK(_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From MSDN documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#iactionresult-type)

> The ActionResult types represent various HTTP status codes. Any
> non-abstract class deriving from ActionResult qualifies as a valid
> return type

In your case, API expecting to return HTTP status code, not a boolean value, so return status code with your boolean value

```
public ActionResult CheckSignedIn()
{
    return Ok(_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User));
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error if I do ```OK``` but not if I do ```Ok```, and what does doing either do?

Comment: Ok, thank you, what does putting 'Ok' in front of the rest do?

Comment: Ok is one of HTTP status code. Every ActionResult expect status code with the response. Ok response states that request is successfully processed and it return 200OK as a status code. It represent `Success`. For more information: [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)